# Django doesn't create a {{ debug }} variable in DEBUG mode

Tags: django, debugging

As of the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug), there should be variables called "debug" and "sql_queries" usable in templates if all requirements are met.

I have set the following (and checked their values with the [debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)):

- `DEBUG = True`
- `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True`
- `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` left at its default value (containing 'django.core.context_processors.debug')
- `INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)` (and the debug toolbar shows `REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'` under "HTTP Headers")
- `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = "(invalid variable '%s'!)"`

When rendering a template containing `{{ sql_queries }} {{ debug }}`, I get `(invalid variable 'sql_queries'!) (invalid variable 'debug'!)` as output.

My Django version is 1.2.3. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, are you creating a `Context`, or a `RequestContext`?  It needs to be `RequestContext`.

Comment: Well, I'm just using `render_to_response("some.template.file")`.

Comment: The docs include this text: "If you need to use context processors, render the template with a RequestContext instance instead. Your code might look something like this:  render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
"

Comment: Okay that helped me find the answer, thank you very much! A `RequestContext` instance must be passed explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Ned Batchelder's answer led me to the right direction. A `RequestContext` instance must be explicitly passed when using `render_to_response`:

```
return render_to_response("some.template.file",
                          templateArguments,
                          context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

From Django 1.3, you can use the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function as shorthand:

```
return render(request, "some.template.file", templateArguments)
```

Comment: `return render( request, "some.template.file", templateArguments )` is shorter and by default it uses `RequestContext`.

Comment: @hobbes3: Right, that was introduced in 1.3 - I grew up using the old variant. Edited my answer, thanks!